# where is magento2 admin bundle product special price file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, bundled-product, special-price

bundle product in magento2 admin special price. I want edit the file but i can't find the file path. can anyone please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the File path,

```
 vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml
```